# PMD installation in IBM RAD and Rules Set

Tags: pmd

I installed the latest PMD plugin in IBM RAD, however I find that the Rule Configuration under Windows --> Preferences --> PMD --> Rule Configuration is blank. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse-pmd then you'll find the PMD settings in the project properties. There are instructions on [how to get started with eclipse-pmd](http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/getting-started.html) on  its website.